# Как сделать подобное меню?

Tags: java, android

При добавлении bottom navigation view получается такое меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как сделать такое (оно еще вконтакте и на ютубе, например),то есть чтобы без подписей и с подчеркиванием активного меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `TabLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо подписей можешь использовать SVG иконки. О том, как сделать меню с подчеркиваниями, можешь почитать [тут](http://www.fandroid.info/android-sliding-tabs-razdvizhnye-vkladki-v-stile-material-design/).